# Jquery Anything Slider Nav Bar Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, anythingslider

I created a custom nav bar function for the Anything Slider that will switch slides based on which 'button' is clicked. I need to also write something that will toggle the 'current' class when one of the slider arrows is pushed but I can't find the event name to look for or where to insert a callback function.

Any help would be appreciated. I've included my nav bar function if it helps.

```
$('nav ul li').click(function(){ 

    $('nav ul li').removeClass('current'); // reset current menu button

        var slideName = $(this).attr('class'); // get class name

        $(this).toggleClass('current'); // make button current

        $('section.about_us').fadeOut('slow');
        $('#about_us_container').fadeOut('slow', function(){ // hide about us page

        switch (slideName){ //change slide
            case 'navItem1':
                $('#slider').anythingSlider(1);
                    break;
            case 'navItem2':
                $('#slider').anythingSlider(2);
                break;
            case 'navItem3':
                $('#slider').anythingSlider(3);
                break;
            case 'navItem4':
                $('#slider').anythingSlider(4);
                break;
            case 'navItem5':
                $('#slider').anythingSlider(5);
            default:
                //do nothing
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the `appendControlsTo` option and have the plugin do all the work ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Cm479/9/)).

In the [latest verison](https://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider) of AnythingSlider (version 1.7+), you can append the arrows (separately), control panel (navigation + play button), navigation, or just the play button to any element on the page.

Or, if you need to keep your menu intact, try this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Cm479/124/)):

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider({
    // If true, builds a list of anchor links to link to each panel
    buildNavigation: false,
    onSlideComplete: function(slider){
        $('nav ul li').eq(slider.currentPage-1).trigger('click');
    }
});

$('nav ul li').click(function() {
    // prevent infinite loop
    if ($(this).is('.current')) { return; }

    $('nav ul li').removeClass('current'); // reset current menu button
    var slideName = $(this).attr('class'); // get class name
    $(this).toggleClass('current'); // make button current

    $('#slider').anythingSlider(slideName.slice(-1));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Having looked over the plugin source, I don't think it broadcasts events when the arrows are clicked. That would be very easy to add in, but if you don't want to modify the plugin, after the plugin code is run, you can just bind your own click handlers to the arrows, then in those handlers, get the current page and the numbers of pages via AnythingSlider's external API:

```
var current = $('#slider').data('AnythingSlider').currentPage
var pages = $('#slider').data('AnythingSlider').pages
```

Note that the `var current` will provide the  page number *before* the click, so you'll need  to add or subtract one and make sure you're handling the end-of-range properly. Then with the real current page determined, you should be able to apply the `current` class to your desired `LI`.

As an aside: since you're going to be adding a current class to these LIs, I think you'll have issues with your `switch` statement when `$(this).attr('class')` returns `'navItem2 current'` instead of just `'navItem2'`. Some refactoring of that will probably save you pain later.

Comment: Hey there Rob, and thanks for your answer. I ended up fishing around some more @ GitHub and found the proper documentation. Apparently there ARE events for anything from slider initialization to slide begin to slide end. (in case you're curious it's all here - https://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider/wiki/Callbacks-and-Events)

Regarding your aside, I appreciate the concern but if a navItem that's set to current is to be clicked then nothing should happen anyway.

Once again, thanks for your answer. As far as I'm concerned whiskey DOES count as a beer :D

Comment: Aha... I had googled it and just viewed the v1.4 source from here, where it may have originated... http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/js/jquery.anythingslider.js